# Creating Matrix with triple pointer causes Segmentation Fault

Tags: c, pointers, matrix

I need to implement a matrix_create function that receives a triple pointer.
It compiles well, but when I run it I get the Segmentation Fault error, probably because I messed up somewhere in the memory allocation.
But I cannot find my mistake.

The code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int matrix_create(int ***m, int ze, int sp);
void matrix_init(int **m, int ze, int sp);

int main (void)
{
    int ze = 3;
    int sp = 3;
    int i,j;
    int ***m = malloc(sizeof(int**));
    *m = malloc(ze * sizeof(int*));

    matrix_create(m, ze, sp);
    matrix_init(*m, ze, sp);
    for(i = 0; i < ze; ++i) {
        for(j = 0; j < sp; ++j)
            printf("%i\n", *m[i][j]);
    }
    return 0;
}

int matrix_create(int ***m, int ze, int sp)
{
    int i, k;
    if (!*m)
        return 0;
    for (i = 0; i < ze; ++i) {
        *m[i] = malloc(sp * sizeof(int));
        if (!*m[i]) {
            for (k = 0; k < i; ++k)
                free(*m[k]);
            free(*m);
            return 0;
        }
    }
    return 1;
}

void matrix_init(int **m, int ze, int sp)
{
    int i,j;
    for(i = 0; i < ze; ++i) {
        for(j = 0; j < sp; ++j)
            m[i][j] = rand() % 1000;
    }
}
```

Comment: Step one: Get your code indentation right.

Comment: Why are you doing part of the creation in `main`?

Comment: Tip: Yelling PLEASE HELP ME does not make anyone more motivated to help you.

Comment: It's almost always better to allocate a one dimensional array of size `x*y*z` instead of an `x` sized array of pointers to `y` pointers to `z` sized arrays. The amount of memory allocated for these intermediate arrays is considerable, plus it spreads your data out all over the place needlessly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The index operator `[]` takes precedence over the indirection operator `*`.
 See [C Operator Precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence).

This means you have to change

```
*m[i]
```

to

```
(*m)[i]
```

in the function `matrix_create`:

```
(*m)[i] = malloc(sp * sizeof(int));
if (!(*m)[i]) {
    .....
}
```

and in the main program:

```
printf("%i\n", (*m)[i][j]);
```